# The Alpha Vantage API call for DIGITAL_CURRENCY_WEEKLY is not working

Tags: alpha-vantage

This example is for https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/

You should be able to just paste this into your browser:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=DIGITAL_CURRENCY_WEEKLY&symbol=BTC&market=CNY&apikey=demo

Result:
{
"Error Message": "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for DIGITAL_CURRENCY_WEEKLY."
}

Is the API down or has the documentation changed?

Testing with my free api key, also fails.
I've also tried it with a VPN so I don't think my IP is being blocked.

At least one other API call is working so I can confirm the server(s) is not down.

Comment: The API is working now with no changes on my part. If someone knows of an Alpha Vantage status page, please post here or let me know. I have reached out to their technical support, but don't have anything to report yet.